# CSS - How to keep floating Child Elements past its Parent Width

Tags: css

What is the CSS approach to have child elements ie: `.sub` (green colored divs) to always float to the left **without** breaking into a second line regardless of the **viewport**?

[image]

In another words I'd like to position N amount of child elements floating to the left, and when it reaches the width of its parent container to **keep** floating in **one line** hiding the overflow.

I thought that by setting `overflow: hidden` on the parent container would do it, however I must be missing other CSS properties here to accomplish the desired behavior.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  ...... more .sub divs below
</div>


body {
    background-color: blue;

}

.container{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub {
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  width: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use flex (*the initial value of `flex-wrap` is `nowrap`*)

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

.container{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  flex:0 0 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
  <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

---

You could use `display:inline-box` on the `.sub` elements and make their container `white-space:nowrap` (*need to remove the whitespace between the nodes, or use trick like `font-size:0` on the container etc.*)

```css
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

.container{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.sub {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  width:120px;
  display:inline-block;
  white-space:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div class="sub"></div><div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll go through your suggestions.